# Illegal characters in OrientDB graph for property-type string

Tags: indexing, orientdb, illegal-characters

I use the graph version of OrientDB. Now I created a schema-less class, where I want to index a variable. This variable needs to become a property first. But when I try to create this property - of type string (or binary, or whatever) - it responds:

```
com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OSchemaException: The database contains some schema-less data in the property 'clazz.clazz_name' that is not compatible with the type STRING. Fix those records and change the schema again [ONetworkProtocolHttpDb]
```

So I need to fix something, but what? What characters are illegal for a variable to become a property so that it can be indexed? (BTW, lists are also not an option)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was indeed a problem I created.
I created a super-class where the property had to be created. One of the sub-classes inserted a List instead of a String. So when querying all vertices of sub-type

```
final Iterable<Vertex> iterable = this.graph.getVerticesOfClass("clazz");
```

I printed all types of clazz_name by `vertex.getProperty("clazz_name").getClass().getName()` where I saw OLinkedList. Reinserting those vertices fixed my problem.